# RestKit POSTs object to server, but server receives empty GET request

Tags: ios, ios6, restkit

When I use the `postObject` method in RestKit, everything seems okay by the log (see below).

But on the server, the request is received as `GET` and the request body is empty, instead of being a `POST` and containing the serialized object.

```
2013-01-12 14:40:08.860 AppName[3953:c07] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:152 POST 'http://urlgoeshere.com'
```

Below is the code I am using for the `POST` and the RestKit initialization. I am using RestKit 0.20.0-pre6.

**POST Object to Server**

```
// CREATE THE MANAGED OBJECT, AND SAVE IT
RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore];
Message *msg = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
msg.note = @"This is a sample message.";
msg.dateCreated = [NSDate date];
[objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext save:nil];

// BUILD THE REQUEST MAPPING & REQUEST DESCRIPTOR
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"messageId": @"id",
 @"dateCreated": @"date_created",
 }];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"note" ]];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[Message class] rootKeyPath:@"message"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

// SEND POST REQUEST TO SERVER
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:msg
                                       path:@"/path/to/messages"
                                 parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] userId] forKey:@"user_id"]
                                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                        NSLog(@"success!");
                                    }
                                    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"failure.\n\n%@", [error description]);
                                    }
 ];
```

**RestKit Initialization in App Delegate**

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlgoeshere.com"];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// Initialize managed object store
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

// Setup our object mappings    
RKEntityMapping *messageMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
messageMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"messageId" ];
[messageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id": @"messageId",
 @"date_created": @"dateCreated",
 }];
[messageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"note" ]];

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DBNameHere.sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of server are you talking to? I would suspect that your server is doing a redirect or something. RestKit uses NSURLConnection to make the requests, so its extremely unlikely that the issue is client side as what you see reported in the logs is read directly from the NSURLRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Blake. You are absolutely right. When I accessed "/path", it was redirecting on the server to "/path/". That is why `GET` requests were working fine from RestKit, but not any other request method. I appreciate your help!